# POST request redirects to php file

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Sorry, im new to php and post requests so it might be a dumb question. Im trying to create a contact form. Im using a post request to send it to a php file so that it can then send an email. Yet for some reason whenever i do so, instead of sending an email it redirects it to an empty page with a plaintext version of the PHP file. Am i doing something wrong?

```
<div class="page">
  <form class="contact-form" method="POST" action="./scripts/email.php" name="myemailform">
    <label for="name">Full Name (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-item" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="email">Email (required)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-item" id="email" name="email">

    <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" class="form-item" id="phone" name="phone">

    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-item" id="address" name="address">

    <label for="message">Message (required)</label>
    <textarea id="message" class="form-item" name="message" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "New form submissions";

    function problem($error)
    {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br><br>";
        echo $error . "<br><br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br><br>";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (
        !isset($_POST['Name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['Message'])
    ) {
        problem('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['Name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['Message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br>';
    }

    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        problem($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

The PHP is directly copied from an example but i have tried multiple.

I tried to change the PHP code, and tried different examples to see if this was the fault. Also tried to add the PHP directly to the HTML file but that did not work either.

Comment: Make sure 1) you're using a webserver and accessing the files via `http://localhost` (assuming you're testing this on your local machine), 2) that your webserver has PHP installed in it, and 3) your file is named with a `.php` extension.

Comment: `I tried to change the PHP code`... if it's _displaying_ the PHP code, then it's clearly not executing it, so changing it won't make any difference. The environment is at fault, not the code. See above.

Comment: P.S. FYI `$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" ` is very likely to end with your message flagged as spam/spoofing and thus blocked or sent to junk. You can't legitimately send an email on behalf of someone else's email account! Instead use fixed a `From` address whose domain matches the domain of the email server you're using.  If you need to know the email of the person who submitted the form, put that info in the message body and/or the Reply-To header of the email. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5947043 for a fantastic guide to debugging email-sending issues in PHP